# Чи потрібне тире у другому абзаці прямої мови в межах однієї репліки?

Tags: правопис, пунктуація, пряма-мова

У [правописі 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) багато чого написано про пряму мову (§ 167), але відповіді на це питання не знайшов.

Якщо пряма мова починається з абзацу (тоді перед нею ставимо тире), а продовжується ще одним абзацем (тобто для продовження оповіді тим самим персонажем потрібно розділити репліку на абзаци), чи потрібно ставити ще одне тире?

Приблизний вигляд того, про що я питаю:

> Тоді він почав оповідати:
>
> — Але щоб ви зрозуміли, звідки виникає це хибне уявлення людей, цуратись насолоди і вихваляти страждання, я розкрию перед вами всю картину і роз’ясню, що саме говорив цей чоловік, який відкрив істину, якого я б назвав зодчим щасливого життя. [...]
>
> **(???)** Але ми цураємось і вважаємо, що  заслуговують справедливого обурення ті, хто, піддався звабі і розбещеним спокусам, які дають їм насолоду, і без тями від пристрасті не передбачили, яких страждань і які нещастя на них чекають. [...]

Питання: чи потрібно на місці трьох знаків питання у дужках ставити ще одне тире?

Answer (score 1):

У російській мові в аналогічній ситуації тире **не ставиться**:

> Если передается длинный рассказ со многими абзацами, то тире ставится только перед первым абзацем (ни перед промежуточными абзацами, ни перед последним тире не ставятся):
>
> *— Работа нашей экспедиции проходила так, — начал свой рассказ учёный-геолог. — Был разработан подробный план, намечены маршруты… [Продолжает рассказ.]*
>
> *Таковы предварительные результаты экспедиции.*
>
> <sup>([Д. Э. Розенталь, «Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация», § 53.7](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161,7#ppp_7).)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Якщо передається довга розповідь / довге оповідання з багатьма абзацами, то тире ставиться тільки перед першим абзацем (ні перед проміжними абзацами, ні перед останнім тире не ставляться):
>
> *— Робота нашої експедиції проходила так, — почав свою розповідь учений-геолог. — Було розроблено докладний план, намічено маршрути… [Продовжує розповідь.]*
>
> *Такі попередні результати експедиції.*
>
> <sup>([Д. Е. Розенталь, «Довідник з російської мови: орфографія й пунктуація», § 53.7](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161,7#ppp_7).)</sup>

Я колись ставив питання, [чи є якісь реальні відмінності між російськими й українськими традиціями пунктуації](/q/75) (мабуть, дурне, бо надто широке). Хоча я не отримав відповіді, яка б мене на 100% влаштувала, і питання для мене досі лишається відкритим, але я не думаю, що конкретно в цьому випадку ми робимо якось по-іншому.

Зазначу, що в такому випадку може бути доречно періодично виходити з прямої мови, щоб читачу було очевидніше, що це все ще пряма мова і хто саме мовить:

> Він почав розповідати:
>
> — Бла-бла-бла.
>
> Бла-бла-бла**, — продовжував він. —** Бла-бла-бла.
>
> Бла-бла-бла**, — зізнався він, поправляючи окуляри. —** Бла-бла-бла.

Зверніть увагу, що якщо новий абзац тексту починається з опису зовнішньої (по відношенню до прямої мови) ситуації, то подальшу пряму мову ми оформлюємо як від самого початку, знову ставлячи тире:

> Він почав розповідати:
>
> — Бла-бла-бла.
>
> **Він поставив недопиту склянку води на стіл і повернувся до розповіді:**
>
> **— Бла-бла-бла.**

Це можна використовувати як засіб, якщо Вам не подобається продовжувати пряму мову з нового абзацу без тире (почавши новий абзац із опису зовнішнього світу, Ви потім можете продовжувати пряму мову з тире). Але зловживати цим, мабуть, теж не варто.

Також часто в таких випадках внутрішню розповідь ми оформлюємо не як пряму мову:

> — Оксано, як ти потрапив у цю халепу? — спитав Остап.
>
> Оксана замислилася й почала розповідати.
>
> П'ять років тому, коли Оксана вперше <…>, сталося <…>. І тоді вона вперше  <…>. А потім <…>.

(Можна навіть оформити внутрішню розповідь як окремий розділ.)

Можна почати внутрішню розповідь як пряму мову, а продовжити її, інтегрувавши в текст:

> **Тоді Сергій почав оповідати:**
>
> — Але щоб ви зрозуміли, звідки виникає це хибне уявлення людей, цуратись насолоди і вихваляти страждання, я розкрию перед вами всю картину і роз’ясню, що саме говорив цей чоловік, який відкрив істину, якого я б назвав зодчим щасливого життя.
>
> **І Сергій продовжив розкривати свої погляди, погляди, до яких прийшов раптово й неочікувано після випадкової бесіди з незнайомим чоловіком, але які він проніс через усе життя.**
>
> <s>Дійсно</s>Ніхто не відкидає, не зневажає, не уникає насолод тільки через те, що це насолоди, але лише через те, що тих, хто не вміє розумно вдаватися насолоді, осягають великі страждання**, казав він**. Так само як немає нікого, хто полюбивши, вважав за краще і зажадав би саме страждання тільки за те, що це страждання, а не тому, що інший раз виникають такі обставини, коли страждання і біль приносять якесь і чималу насолоду. Якщо скористатися найпростішим прикладом, то хто з нас став би займатися якими б то не було тяжкими фізичними вправами, якщо б це не приносило з собою якоїсь користі? І хто міг би по справедливості дорікнути прагнення до насолоди, яке не несло б з собою ніяких неприємностей, або того, хто уникав би такого страждання, яке не приносило б з собою ніякої насолоди?
>
> Але ми цураємось і вважаємо, що заслуговують справедливого обурення ті, хто, піддався звабі і розбещеним спокусам, які дають їм насолоду, і без тями від пристрасті не передбачили, яких страждань і які нещастя на них чекають. Вони винні так само, як і ті, хто через душевну слабкість, тобто через бажання уникнути страждань і болю відмовляється від виконання свого обов’язку. Втім, тут дуже легко і просто провести відмінності, тому що, коли ми вільні і нам надана повна можливість вибору бажаного, коли ніщо не заважає нам робити те, що нам більше подобається, будь яку насолоду слід визнати бажаним, а будь-яке страждання огидним. Але при деяких обставинах – або на вимогу боргу, або в силу якоїсь необхідності часто доводиться забувати про насолоди і не втікати від тягарів. Тому мудрець дотримується в цьому випадку наступного принципу вибору – або, відмовляючись від задоволення, він отримує якісь інші і навіть великі насолоди, або, зазнаючи страждання, він позбавляється від більш жорстоких.
>
> **Так казав Сергій, а Дмитро й Людмила мовчки слухали й не знали, чи погуджуватись їм чи ні…**

Також можна чергувати пряму мову й непряму. (Оформлюючи як пряму мову ті фрагменти, які бажано зацитувати дослівно або про які бажано підкреслити, що це аж ніяк не думка автора, й інтегруючи в текст інші.)

P.S.:

- А ще можна з лапками, тоді все буде простіше (але якщо загальний стиль тексту такий, що висловлені вголос думки оформлені без лапок, то, звісно, не варто порушувати його заради одного випадку).
- Див. також [чимось схоже запитання про рос. мову](//rus.stackexchange.com/q/435565) і частково пов'язані запитання про англ. мову (але вони якраз про лапки, а в англ. мові правила лапок складніші) — [q2288](//english.stackexchange.com/q/2288), [q96608](//english.stackexchange.com/q/96608).